# Are Unions of simply connected sets still simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, connectedness

Is this true? I would like to use this fact to make a different proof more intuitive and readable, but don't see how to justify it.

Comment: This claim is simply false.  You should easily be able to generate counterexamples.

Comment: If the intersection is path connected then yes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A circle is not simply connected, but you can write it as an union of two half-circles, each of which is simply connected.

Comment: Is there a general way/algorithm to disprove simple connectedness of a union? Take for example the complex plane without the imaginary axis, $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{x+\mathrm{i}y \mid x = 0\}$

Comment: If there is, I am not aware of it.